# Using (of/on) after examination

Tags: prepositions

"Performing clinical examinations of patients" or "Performing clinical examinations on patients" which one is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them are fine & correct. (But not here in this context)

As you definitely know what "[perform something on somebody/something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/perform+on)
" means, it's better to say:

> "**Performing** clinical examinations[something] **on** patients[somebody]"

"Performing chemistry[something] examinations on salt water[something]"

"Performing post-mortem[something] examinations on dead bodies[something]"

See also:

> **examination on**
>
> e.g. "We also performed calcium score **examinations on 172 patients** with high pretest risk; of these patients, 50 had a zero calcium score,..."
>
> e.g. "Moreover, despite the higher diagnostic yield of CE compared with other diagnostic tools, the actual impacts of this **examination on patient** outcome remain poorly defined."
>   .
>
> **examination of**
>
> e.g. "**Examinations of patients** with RA show an increased number of specific antibodies and the DNA of these bacteria in the blood and synovial liquid"
>
> e.g. "These facilities, often described as "pill mills," employed doctors who wrote narcotics prescriptions after cursory **examinations of patients**."